# Negative number of delete votes left?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deletion

I didn't remember if I had used up all my delete votes today, so I tried to delete one. I was greeted with this:

[image: Deletion dialog box]

As you can see, I have -1 (negative one) delete votes left today. How did that happen? I still have between 14k and 15k rep, just like this morning, so my number of delete votes shouldn't have changed.

Comment: Did you self-delete something?

Comment: Likely reason: [the accounting of delete votes is a buggy mess](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274832/3717023).

Comment: Well, these votes are imaginary. So it's not fully surprising to see negative ones as well.

Comment: @quid I did, actually. So if I understand correctly I need to use up all my delete votes before deleting my own posts...?

Comment: For most "effective" usage, yes, at least this is what @Fundamental claims. I never ran into this myself; I merely read on the meta.SE FAQ on deletion (I think) that there was some (there unspecified) inconsistency with respect to self-deletion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For ease of reference, I adapt a part of my answer to meta.SO post [Why is deleting own posts consuming delete votes..?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274757#274832)

Each 10K users has two kinds of delete votes:

- all-purpose delete votes (between 5 and 30, the number depends on reputation)
- self-delete votes (5; these are available under 10K too)

The software uses all-purpose delete votes as long as you have them, even if you are deleting your own post. This means that to avoid wasting the delete votes on self-deletes, one should postpone them until there are no all-purpose votes left for the day.

To calculate the number of remaining delete votes, software subtracts the *total* number of delete votes cast so far from the number of *all-purpose* delete votes available. The result may be negative, as you observed.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamental is correct.  This is a display issue as well so the next build will show zero instead of a negative number if you have < 0.

Comment: How about fixing it *properly* by subtracting the "delete own post" votes from the "delete own posts" count?

Comment: I agree with Lord Farin, and changing the display without changing the actual behavior takes away information that might be useful.  But I suppose it might also take away some confusion and cause fewer meta questions about the behavior.